# how can I return different images everyday according to the date

Tags: c#

i want to return 30 images according to the date in c# 
is it possible ?
like that

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, 2).ToString() + ".png");
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an image? Grab an image stored on your file system?  You haven't conveyed anything?

Comment: You code sample will only have ONE bitmap object.  Where are you getting these 30 images?  From your local drive, from the resources of your project?

Comment: `string.Format("{0}.png", DateTime.Month)` might be simpler

Comment: actually i want to develop application that use 3 web browser and 1 picturebox.. it will be returned 3 web browser and one picturebox every 2 minutes during the day(note: i did that using timer).when it get past the another day the same situation will repeat but only will change picturebox. it will used another image. it will used all images resources of my project. I dont know load image from resources of my project to picturebox for every day. Please could you help to me for this problem @Shar1er80

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
     const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        string[] filteredFiles = files.Where(x => x.LastWriteTime >= today.AddDays(-30)).Select(y => y.FullName).ToArray();
    }
```